# got the Error " Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 4 arguments."

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a logic in google sheets. But return #N/A as mentioned in the title, what did i do wrong?

=if(and(Z598>=time(8,0,),Z598<=time(10,0,),Y598<=$M$4,Y598>time(10,0,), OR(N598 = "MLS", S598= "MLS")),90,
if(and(Z598>=time(8,0,),Z598<=time(10,0,),Y598>=$M$4, OR(N598 = "MLS", S598 = "MLS")),(time(8,0,)-Y598+1),
if(and(Z598>=time(8,0,),Z598<=time(10,0,),Y598=time(0,0,), OR(N598 = "MLS", S598= "MLS")),time(8,0,),
if(and(Z598<time(8,0,),Y598>time(10,0,), Y598<$M$4, OR(N598 = "MLS", S598 = "MLS")),Z598-$M$4+1,
if(and(Z598<time(8,1,0),Y598=time(0,0,0), OR(N598 = "MLS", S598 = "MLS")),Z598,
if(and(Y598>time(0,0,), Y598<time(8,1,), Z598>time(8,0,), OR(N598 = "MLS", S598 = "MLS")),time(8,0,)-Y598,
if(and(Y598<$M$4,Y598>time(11,0,),Z598<time(23,59,),Z598>$M$4, OR(N598 = "MLS", S598 = "MLS")),Z598-$M$4,
if(and(Y598=$M$4,Y598>time(11,0,),Z598<=time(8,0,), OR(N598 = "MLS", S598 = "MLS")),Z598-$M$4+1,
if(and(Z598<time(8,0,),Y598>$M$4, OR(N598 = "MLS", S598 = "MLS")),((1-(Y598-time(0,0,)))+Z598),
if(and(Y598>time(0,0,),Y598<time(8,0,),Z598<=time(8,0,), OR(N598 = "MLS", S598= "MLS")),Z598-Y598, "")))))))))*24*10,
if(and(Z598>=time(8,0,),Z598<=time(10,0,),Y598<=$M$4,Y598>time(10,0,), OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),36,
if(and(Z598>=time(8,0,),Z598<=time(10,0,),Y598>=$M$4, OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),(time(8,0,)-Y598+1),
if(and(Z598>=time(8,0,),Z598<=time(10,0,),Y598=time(0,0,), OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),time(8,0,),
if(and(Z598<time(8,0,),Y598>time(10,0,), Y598<$M$4, OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),Z598-$M$4+1,
if(and(Z598<time(8,1,0),Y598=time(0,0,0), OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),Z598,
if(and(Y598>time(0,0,), Y598<time(8,1,), Z598>time(8,0,), OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),time(8,0,)-Y598,
if(and(Y598<$M$4,Y598>time(11,0,),Z598<time(23,59,),Z598>$M$4, OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),Z598-$M$4,
if(and(Y598=$M$4,Y598>time(11,0,),Z598<=time(8,0,), OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),Z598-$M$4+1,
if(and(Z598<time(8,0,),Y598>$M$4, OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),((1-(Y598-time(0,0,)))+Z598),
if(and(Y598>time(0,0,),Y598<time(8,0,),Z598<=time(8,0,), OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),Z598-Y598, "")))))))))*24*4))

i would like to create the logic, If MLS is selected, the time is multiplied by 10, if not, it is multiplied by 4.

Answer (score 0):

My first bit of advice is to stop doing this to yourself. That pile of code is not self-explanatory, editor-friendly, nor (as you've seen) maintainable. Myself, I'd immediately start breaking it out into a hidden helper column or somesuch, but assuming you want to keep the monolithic mega-cell, we can at least parse and reformat it to something like:

```
=if(
    and(Z598>=time(8,0,),Z598<=time(10,0,),Y598<=$M$4,Y598>time(10,0,), OR(N598 = "MLS", S598= "MLS")),
    90,
    if(
        and(Z598>=time(8,0,),Z598<=time(10,0,),Y598>=$M$4, OR(N598 = "MLS", S598 = "MLS")),
        (time(8,0,)-Y598+1),
        if(
            and(Z598>=time(8,0,),Z598<=time(10,0,),Y598=time(0,0,), OR(N598 = "MLS", S598= "MLS")),
            time(8,0,),
            if(
                and(Z598<time(8,0,),Y598>time(10,0,), Y598<$M$4, OR(N598 = "MLS", S598 = "MLS")),
                Z598-$M$4+1,
                if(
                    and(Z598<time(8,1,0),Y598=time(0,0,0), OR(N598 = "MLS", S598 = "MLS")),
                    Z598,
                    if(
                        and(Y598>time(0,0,), Y598<time(8,1,), Z598>time(8,0,), OR(N598 = "MLS", S598 = "MLS")),
                        time(8,0,)-Y598,
                        if(
                            and(Y598<$M$4,Y598>time(11,0,),Z598<time(23,59,),Z598>$M$4, OR(N598 = "MLS", S598 = "MLS")),
                            Z598-$M$4,
                            if(
                                and(Y598=$M$4,Y598>time(11,0,),Z598<=time(8,0,), OR(N598 = "MLS", S598 = "MLS")),
                                Z598-$M$4+1,
                                if(
                                    and(Z598<time(8,0,),Y598>$M$4, OR(N598 = "MLS", S598 = "MLS")),
                                    ((1-(Y598-time(0,0,)))+Z598),
                                    if(
                                        and(Y598>time(0,0,),Y598<time(8,0,),Z598<=time(8,0,), OR(N598 = "MLS", S598= "MLS")),
                                        Z598-Y598,
                                        ""
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    2410,
    if(
        and(Z598>=time(8,0,),Z598<=time(10,0,),Y598<=$M$4,Y598>time(10,0,), OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),
        36,
        if(
            and(Z598>=time(8,0,),Z598<=time(10,0,),Y598>=$M$4, OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),
            (time(8,0,)-Y598+1),
            if(
                and(Z598>=time(8,0,),Z598<=time(10,0,),Y598=time(0,0,), OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),
                time(8,0,),
                if(
                    and(Z598<time(8,0,),Y598>time(10,0,), Y598<$M$4, OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),
                    Z598-$M$4+1,
                    if(
                        and(Z598<time(8,1,0),Y598=time(0,0,0), OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),
                        Z598,
                        if(
                            and(Y598>time(0,0,), Y598<time(8,1,), Z598>time(8,0,), OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),
                            time(8,0,)-Y598,
                            if(
                                and(Y598<$M$4,Y598>time(11,0,),Z598<time(23,59,),Z598>$M$4, OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),
                                Z598-$M$4,
                                if(
                                    and(Y598=$M$4,Y598>time(11,0,),Z598<=time(8,0,), OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),
                                    Z598-$M$4+1,
                                    if(
                                        and(Z598<time(8,0,),Y598>$M$4, OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),
                                        ((1-(Y598-time(0,0,)))+Z598),
                                        if(
                                            and(Y598>time(0,0,),Y598<time(8,0,),Z598<=time(8,0,), OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),
                                            Z598-Y598,
                                            ""
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        244
    )
)
```

Google Sheets wont miss a beat upon hitting those newlines and indents, but now the overall structure is clearer.

Collapsing some formulas, it's visible that indeed—some commas or parens are currently mislaid, leaving your IFs with the wrong number of arguments:

```
=if(
    and(Z598>=time(8,0,),Z598<=time(10,0,),Y598<=$M$4,Y598>time(10,0,), OR(N598 = "MLS", S598= "MLS")),
    90,
    if(<snip>
    )2410,
    if(
        and(Z598>=time(8,0,),Z598<=time(10,0,),Y598<=$M$4,Y598>time(10,0,), OR(N598 <> "MLS", S598 <> "MLS")),
        36,
        if(<snip>
        )244
    )
)
```

I don't know your overall intent, but I hope that with the structure above you can see where the error is and repair your formula.